# What information is supplied to sites when logging in with Steam OpenID?

Tags: steam

I've been curious as to what details about my steam account or profile is supplied when I log into a website or service using the Steam OpenID service.

Which details are being supplied and how personal are they?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Are you asking what is provided to steam? Or are you asking what is provided to third parties when you sign in using steam on non-steam sites, just like how arqade lets you sign in using steam?

Comment: This question should be moved to Meta, it isn't about a game but this site... and I misread this as asking about Arqade's site login with steam... my bad.

Comment: Almost more of a SO question, really. Not entirely about Arqade, more about the system Arqade happens to use? Technically this sort of answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619848/retrieving-openid-data-of-a-steam-account-returning-null

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Steam's OpenID service, which is non-gaming related. It is better suited at [Web Applications SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can/should it be migrated? @galacticninja

Comment: Not quite sure why. Arqade isn't the only application which utilizes Steam's OpenID. This question is also not related to development, so would not be on topic on SO. The help center explicitly lists *Game-specific hardware and utilities* as on topic here. This question seems to fit fine within this qualification.

Comment: @msg45f The question doesn't belong on Arqade despite that snippet you've found. It doesn't ask about this site, which would only make it on-topic on Meta and it doesn't ask about a game or utility for a game. It asks for an authentication's data to log on site and applications, which is really not on-topic here.

Comment: Sorry everyone if this isn't the right place to post such a question i just thought since there's a category for steam related questions that this would be ok but i'm guessing that's not the case. So apologies for that, what i wanted to know is what information/details are provided to third parties and not what is provided to steam. Jeeva has answered what i wanted to know in the answer below so i'll mark this as answered.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Steam is a utility for games. We get a lot of questions about Steam. This question is also not a developer question - it's asking out of concerns of privacy as a user. Both the question and the answer is far more relevant to users on this exchange than any other it would be moved to.

Comment: @msg45f: This question _isn't_ about Steam, though. I see where you're coming from, but it's equivalent to asking what is passed to a given site when you use a Google / Facebook account to sign in. If I hadn't been working on a site using this recently, I probably would have been less into answering it. Glad to hear it helped, though, Slater.

Comment: @Jeeva It's not asking about Facebook/Google authentication. It's asking about Steam's implementation. A feature of **Steam** utilized by users of **Steam**. Other services having similar implementations is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jeeva It probably should be migrated to Web Applications SE. If the mods agree that it should be migrated, they can migrate this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual sign-in process returns very little information to the third party service/website - nothing more than your Steam Name, and your [OpenID URL (which contains your 64-bit Steam ID)](http://steamcommunity.com/dev).

> Steam OpenID Provider
>   Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows your application to authenticate a user's SteamID without requiring them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.) Just download an OpenID library for your language and platform of choice and use http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID. The Claimed ID format is: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/\

Any further information that is returned is made by further calls to the Steam Web API (as shown in the answer by @longtgomjr), and can contain any manner of public information about your profile.
It's worth noting that most data isn't available unless your profile is public. This is **not** a part of the login process, and the retrieval of this data can happen regardless of you logging in.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Valve Software Wiki. Almost all the info that steam has. Read the options available to the sites that use this API here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

According to the read-me on [SteamAuthentication's GitHub page](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication):

> SteamAuthentication is a basic set of PHP files that enable users to login using their steam account to view protected content on your website. it creates a session using their steamid as the sessionID and checks for the session when a user visits the page. It also includes a file which allows you to use their profile information such as their avatar and online status.

I dont know if there is a system in place to see what you share, but I seem to recall that I had to confirm, much like Google's system, when I logged on to the Terraria site with Steam.

Linked from the Wiki's GetPlayerSummeries. The Private Section:

> ```
> realname
>     The player's "Real Name", if they have set it.
> primaryclanid
>     The player's primary group, as configured in their Steam Community profile.
> timecreated
>     The time the player's account was created.
> gameid
>     If the user is currently in-game, this value will be returned and set to the gameid of that game.
> gameserverip
>     The ip and port of the game server the user is currently playing on, if they are playing on-line in a game using Steam matchmaking. Otherwise will be set to "0.0.0.0:0".
> gameextrainfo
>     If the user is currently in-game, this will be the name of the game they are playing. This may be the name of a non-Steam game shortcut.
> cityid
>     This value will be removed in a future update (see loccityid)
> loccountrycode
>     If set on the user's Steam Community profile, The user's country of residence, 2-character ISO country code
> locstatecode
>     If set on the user's Steam Community profile, The user's state of residence
> loccityid
>     An internal code indicating the user's city of residence. A future update will provide this data in a more useful way.
>     steam_location gem/package makes player location data readable for output.
> ```

Comment: As a point, that API covers requests you can make - not the actual return for logging in with OpenID.